# Check if the element in sequence is larger than two previous elements

Tags: python

I want to check the input sequence is super increase, which is the elements in the sequence is larger than sum of previous elements.

for example, sequence (1, 3, 5, 7, 19) is not super increase because 1+3+5>7. Aequence [1, 3, 5, 11, 21] is super increase becuase 1<3, 1+3<5, 1+3+5<11, 1=3=5=11<21. Sequence [0, 0, 1, 2] is not super increase because 0=0. Sequence (-1, 0, 0, 1) is super increase and (1, 2, 0, 4) is not.

I try to wirte my code like this

```
def super_increasing(seq):
    if any(seq[i+1] <= seq[i] for i in range(0,len(seq)-1)):    
        return False 
    else:
        if all(seq[i+2]>seq[i+1]+seq[i] for i in range(0,len(seq)-2)):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

but it says Sequence (-1, 0, 0, 1) is not super increase

How can I fix my code or I just need to change a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with linear complexity using [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
from itertools import accumulate

def super_increasing(seq):
    return all(t < c for c, t in zip(seq[1:], accumulate(seq)))

super_increasing([1, 3, 5, 7, 19])
# False
super_increasing([1, 3, 5, 11, 21])
# True
```

That is basically a short-hand for:

```
def super_increasing(seq):
    t, *rest = seq  # t: running total
    for c in rest:  # c: current element
        if c <= t:
            return False
        t += c
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list slicing and a for loop for this.

Let's loop from 0 to length of the list. and sum all of values from first to `i`th element. If the sum is smaller then the `i`th element of the list the check for the `i`th element is `True`.

```
tf_list = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    tf_list.append(sum(lst[:i]) < lst[i])
```

Now we can see if all values are `True` or not using `all`.

```
print(all(tf_list))
```

More pythonic way is to use list comprehensions:

```
all([sum(lst[:i]) < lst[i] for i in range(len(lst))])
```

Comment: This is quadratic though, There is no need to recalculate the prefix sums again and again.

Comment: I don't understand what did you mean. :( If you wish you can edit the answer. So I can learn what you know. :)

Comment: e.g. for `[1,3,5,11,21]` you are calculating `sum([1,3,5])` and later `sum([1,3,5,11])` which is more expensive than necessary as you could have reused the result from the first.

Comment: Also, the last approach builds an unnecesary in-memory list where a generator would suffice. It also produces wrong results if there is a negative number (or `0`) in the first index.